# cordova platform add android issue on mac

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

Hi im using ionic i already made an ios version of this one and it is successful but when i am creating the android version it has an error

```
Judes-MacBook-Air:ezapp jude$ cordova platform add android
Running command: /Users/judegimeno/desktop/app2/ezapp/hooks/before_platform_add/init_directories.js /Users/judegimeno/desktop/app2/ezapp
Adding android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
    Path: ../../../desktop/app2/ezapp/platforms/android
    Package: com.ezapp
    Name: ezapp
    Activity: MainActivity
    Android target: android-24
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Android project created with cordova-android@6.0.0
Installing "cordova-plugin-console" for android
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-console':CordovaError: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.
    at /Users/judegimeno/desktop/app2/ezapp/platforms/android/cordova/lib/check_reqs.js:222:19
    at _fulfilled (/Users/judegimeno/desktop/app2/ezapp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/judegimeno/desktop/app2/ezapp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/judegimeno/desktop/app2/ezapp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at /Users/judegimeno/desktop/app2/ezapp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:857:14
    at runSingle (/Users/judegimeno/desktop/app2/ezapp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/Users/judegimeno/desktop/app2/ezapp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.
```

Comment: Android SDK is not included in your `PATH` variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Android SDK installed, you can try to do some fix as those errors say:

```
 Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
 Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.
```

But if you don't have Android SDK, please follow official doc to install one. [This is cordova's Android Platform doc](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html)